# About use of parentheses in C

Tags: c, operators

```
void main()
int a,b,c;
c=(a,b)
```

This gives `c=b` while

```
c=a,b
```

gives `c=a`.

What is the reason for the above two?

Comment: Don't use `void main()` - people get upset about it.  The standard is `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: Missing the brackets { } of main.

Answer (score 11):

In this line:

```
c=(a,b)
```

The parentheses mean, "evaluate the expression `a,b` first, then assign the value to `c`." In this case, `b` is assigned, because it's the right-hand-side expression of `a,b`. In C, [comma expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) are evaluated left-to-right, with the overall value being that of the rightmost expression.

While in this line:

```
c=a,b
```

The assignment is evaluated as the entire left hand side first, which is `c=a`. This is because the equal `=` operator takes precedence over the comma `,` operator. Thus, `b` doesn't get assigned to `c` at all. It is equivalent to:

```
(c=a),b
```

Answer (score 3):

In C, the comma operator evaluates the first operand, then discard it and then evaluates the right operand. So the outcome is the right operand. And it has the lowest precedence.

```
c = (a,b)
```

() has higher precedence than, so a,b evaluates first. The result is b. So c = b.

But when used c = a,b assignment = have higher precedence. So c = a evaluates first. Thus a is assigned to c.

Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) for further details.